# iOS - Merge two video into single video file with audio

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, video, merge

I want to merge 2 video files with single file with audio. I am able to merge 2 video files, but after merging ouptut video file does not have any audio sound. Even both old video file have proper audio.I have follow this tutorial: *https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios*  Any suggesiton will be great. Thank guys. 
my code :

```
- (IBAction)MergeAndSave:(id)sender{
if(firstAsset !=nil && secondAsset!=nil){
    [ActivityView startAnimating];
    //Create AVMutableComposition Object.This object will hold our multiple AVMutableCompositionTrack.
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    //VIDEO TRACK
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    [secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];

    //AUDIO TRACK
    if(audioAsset!=nil){
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    } 

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction * MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration));

    //FIXING ORIENTATION//
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *FirstlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *FirstAssetTrack = [[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation FirstAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isFirstAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform firstTransform = FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == 1.0 && firstTransform.c == -1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 0 && firstTransform.b == -1.0 && firstTransform.c == 1.0 && firstTransform.d == 0)  {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isFirstAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(firstTransform.a == 1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == 1.0)   {FirstAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(firstTransform.a == -1.0 && firstTransform.b == 0 && firstTransform.c == 0 && firstTransform.d == -1.0) {FirstAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
    if(isFirstAssetPortrait_){
        FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/FirstAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }else{
        CGAffineTransform FirstAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio,FirstAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [FirstlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(FirstAssetTrack.preferredTransform, FirstAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
    }
    [FirstlayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:firstAsset.duration];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *SecondlayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:secondTrack];
    AVAssetTrack *SecondAssetTrack = [[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageOrientation SecondAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
    BOOL  isSecondAssetPortrait_  = NO;
    CGAffineTransform secondTransform = SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == 1.0 && secondTransform.c == -1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_= UIImageOrientationRight; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 0 && secondTransform.b == -1.0 && secondTransform.c == 1.0 && secondTransform.d == 0)  {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft; isSecondAssetPortrait_ = YES;}
    if(secondTransform.a == 1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == 1.0)   {SecondAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;}
    if(secondTransform.a == -1.0 && secondTransform.b == 0 && secondTransform.c == 0 && secondTransform.d == -1.0) {SecondAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;}
    CGFloat SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.width;
    if(isSecondAssetPortrait_){
        SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio = 320.0/SecondAssetTrack.naturalSize.height;
        CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
    }else{
        ;
        CGAffineTransform SecondAssetScaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio,SecondAssetScaleToFitRatio);
        [SecondlayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(SecondAssetTrack.preferredTransform, SecondAssetScaleFactor),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160)) atTime:firstAsset.duration];
    }


    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstlayerInstruction,SecondlayerInstruction,nil];;

    AVMutableVideoComposition *MainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    MainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:MainInstruction];
    MainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    MainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter.outputURL=url;
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter.videoComposition = MainCompositionInst;
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self exportDidFinish:exporter];
         });
     }];
}
```

}

Comment: Show this tutorial might be help you.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Answer (score 6):

I have created a repo of Multiple videos merge into one video with audio.

**Swift**

https://github.com/Datt1994/DPVideoMerger-Swift

**Objective C**

https://github.com/Datt1994/DPVideoMerger

**Use below code:**

```
 AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
 AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack2 = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[AudioTrack2 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:firstAsset.duration error:nil];
```

**instead of your below code:**

```
if(audioAsset!=nil){
   AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
   [AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)) ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your repo isn't very well documented. Can you explain how to solve the issue in case someone doesn't want to use your repo.

Comment: your repo also doesn't handle different orientation of video clips.

Comment: @Datt1994 Nice demo but when four video are merging into grid form then the audio is not coming. how can fixed it?

Comment: @Datt1994 I am playing two video into grid after merge. But  I need audio as well as. Can you suggest me how I can add the audio composition with video?.